# Change Center position of React leaflet map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

So what I'm trying to do is, I want to change the center of map after I get the users lat and lng,
the code below will make the problem clearer:

```
<LeafletMap
  center={this.state.UserCurrentPosition}
  zoom={17}
  maxZoom={20}
  attributionControl={true}
  zoomControl={false}
  doubleClickZoom={true}
  scrollWheelZoom={true}
  dragging={true}
  animate={true}
  easeLinearity={0.35}
>
  <TileLayer url='https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/alidade_smooth_dark/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png'/>
  <Marker 
    position={this.state.UserCurrentPosition} 
    icon={L.divIcon({
      className: 'user-marker',
      html: `<div  class='icon icon-location'><span class="circle"></span></div>`,
      iconSize: [40, 40],
      iconAnchor: [24, 24]
    })}>
  </Marker>
</LeafletMap>
```

and below is what I'm trying to do:

```
componentDidMount() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showPosition);
}

showPosition = (position) => {
  this.setState({ UserCurrentPosition: [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude] })
}
```

So after I use `setState` to change the user's current position, the marker's position gets updated, but the map's position no, so I was wondering if i'm doing something wrong, or how can it be accomplished.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the center property is only to initialise the map.

You will need to call a map function like `map.panTo(LatLng)` or `map.setView()` when you update the state.

You can use the `useMap()` hook as per this example https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-animated-panning

Comment: in order to do that, i should change my component to functional, and considering what i have done with it, it's a lot of work, is there another way for it maybe?

Comment: I think the alternative is to set and then get a `ref` to your map and then use that within `showPosition()` to call `map.setView()` etc

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the `useMap` hook is accessible in a "descendant" component of a `MapContainer` and NOT outside of it. This is also correct for `useMapEvents` and `useMapEvent` hooks. see docs at https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map/#usemap

Answer (score 9):

Create a separate component as given below:

```
const RecenterAutomatically = ({lat,lng}) => {
 const map = useMap();
  useEffect(() => {
    map.setView([lat, lng]);
  }, [lat, lng]);
  return null;
}
```

Invoke this component inside MapContainer

```
<MapContainer center={[lat, lon]} zoom={80} scrollWheelZoom={true}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='<a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright"></a>'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker position={[lat,lng]}></Marker>
        <RecenterAutomatically lat={lat} lng={lng} />
</MapContainer>
```

So whenever lat and lng changes, the map recenters automatically..